# 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED - Android Studio

Tags: 14.04, emulation, android-studio

- Android Studio 1.3
- Ubuntu 14.04.2
- 64 Bit OS 64 Architecture
- Supports Visualisation
- Lenovo H50 Intel® Core™ i5-4460 Processor
- Graphics: NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 705

I have gone through the steps to install KVM on my system. All checks out okay but I still get this message on running my Nexus 7 2013 Emulator.

Using the line below under run>edit configuration>emulator tab>Additional command line options.

I realise similar questions have been asked but I cannot get it working and perhaps it may help others in a similar situation.

```
-qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm

ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
       you will have to do at least one of the following:
       - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
       - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
       Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
       aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
       Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
```

Comment: Had to reboot before this worked. "source .profile" didn't work for some reason. I may be the last person on earth still running a 32 bit computer. Hey, just got a new video card on ebay for $20, so now my $50 computer can run 720p videos on Youtube with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it strange that I was getting this message as I am running a 64 bit system. I did some further research and dissevered that it was a bug with the kernel.

I updated it as per the solution below and it now works without using force 32 bit.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680018/solved-android-studio-64-bit-error-32-bit-linux-android-emulator-binaries-are

The Kernel below produces no error.

3.13.0-61-generic

Answer (score 0):

Just add  `export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true` in your `.profile` file and run `source .profile`.

I've just done in my laptop and worked.

Comment: that does indeed work. But how do I get it to work with KVM. It says the 32 bit will be dropped in future SDK releases.

Comment: I am using a 64 bit android system!

Comment: Adding -qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm and force 32 bit works - at the same time. And it does seem to run faster. But why is the 32 bit error thrown up and what does it mean going forward?